# Iterating over every permutation of factors of 800 OR possible isomorphism types of abelian groups of orders 74, 147, 666, 800 and 1221

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

**this is self learning**

This may smell of homework but I am doing this http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdf/alg1/p4.pdf worksheet I found, you can see this question is in the "practice" section and dated 4 years ago.

The question is to write down all the possible isomorphism types of an abelien group of order 74, 147, 666, 800 and another of order 1221

**I found the first by luck**

74 / 2 = 37 and 37 is prime, as is 2.

thus: $G\cong\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{37}$

Actually no, that is wrong, as 2 does not divide 37. So only

G$\cong\mathbb{Z}_1\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{37}=\mathbb{Z}_{37}$ is an isomorphism.

**the second**

I've chosen 800 because it's the one I have a feeling is the most difficult, 666 is clearly divisible by 2,3 and 111 which are all prime, so is only an isomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}_{666}$

I now need to find all the combinations of primes that multiply to 800, where I can permute them so that $n_i\lvert n_{i+1}$

I don't want to do this by "brute force" and there should be an algorithm.

My question is this: Have I interpreted the question and the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelien groups correctly? Is there a way to find such permutations of factors?

Comment: Use \oplus for direct sums.

Comment: @T.Bongers it's \cong for the = with a ~ above it ($\cong$) - found it on a "related" question.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) for a way to get symbols quickly, as well.

Comment: The answer to the first one is $\mathbb Z_{74}$, not $\mathbb Z_{37}$.  (By the way, $\mathbb Z_{74}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{2}\times \mathbb Z_{37}$.)  It's all about factorization into primes.  Let me know if that helps ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following result is key to what you want to do:

**Lemma**: If $gcd(r,s)=1$ then $\mathbb Z_r\oplus \mathbb Z_s\cong \mathbb Z_{rs}$.

Now suppose I want to classify all abelian groups of order $800$.

*Step 1.*  Factor $800=2^5 5^2$.

*Step 2.*  Write $2^5 = 2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2=2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2^2=2\cdot 2\cdot 2^3=2\cdot 2^4 = 2^5.$

*Step 3.*  From this, we get five pairwise non-isomorphic abelian groups of order $32$, namely

$\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2$, 
$\;\; \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_4$, 
$\;\;\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_8$, 
$\;\; \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_{16}$, $\;\;\mathbb Z_{32}$.

*Step 4.* Write $25=5\cdot 5 = 5^2$.

*Step 5.*  This gives the two nonisomorphic abelian groups of order $25$:

$\mathbb Z_5\oplus \mathbb Z_5$, $\;\; \mathbb Z_{25}$.

*Step 6.*  Now use the lemma to patch these together. As there are five groups of order $32$ and two groups of order $25$, you will get the following $10$ groups of order $800$  (pairwise non-isomorphic and abelian).  Note that patching always proceeds from right to left.

$(\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2)\oplus (\mathbb Z_5\oplus \mathbb Z_5)\cong \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2 \oplus (\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_5)\oplus (\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_5)\cong \large 
\mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_{10}\oplus \mathbb Z_{10}$

$(\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_4)\oplus (\mathbb Z_5\oplus \mathbb Z_5)\cong \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2 \oplus (\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_5)\oplus (\mathbb Z_4\oplus \mathbb Z_5)\\ \cong 
\large \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_{10}\oplus \mathbb Z_{20}$

$(\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_8)\oplus (\mathbb Z_5\oplus \mathbb Z_5)\cong \mathbb Z_2 \oplus (\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_5)\oplus (\mathbb Z_8\oplus \mathbb Z_5)\\ \cong 
\large \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_{10}\oplus \mathbb Z_{40}$

$(\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_{16})\oplus (\mathbb Z_5\oplus \mathbb Z_5)\cong \mathbb (\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_5)\oplus (\mathbb Z_{16}\oplus \mathbb Z_5)\\ \cong 
\large \mathbb Z_{10}\oplus \mathbb Z_{80}$

$\mathbb Z_{32}\oplus (\mathbb Z_5\oplus \mathbb Z_5)\cong \mathbb Z_5\oplus  (\mathbb Z_{32}\oplus \mathbb Z_5)\\ \cong 
\large \mathbb Z_{5}\oplus \mathbb Z_{160}$

$(\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2)\oplus (\mathbb Z_{25})\cong \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus (\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_{25})\cong \large 
\mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_{2}\oplus \mathbb Z_{50}$

$(\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_4)\oplus (\mathbb Z_{25})\cong \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus (\mathbb Z_4\oplus \mathbb Z_{25})\\ \cong 
\large \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_{2}\oplus \mathbb Z_{100}$

$(\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_8)\oplus (\mathbb Z_{25})\oplus\cong \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2\oplus (\mathbb Z_8\oplus \mathbb Z_{25})\\ \cong 
\large \mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_{2}\oplus \mathbb Z_{200}$

$(\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_{16})\oplus (\mathbb Z_{25}) \cong  \mathbb Z_2 \oplus (\mathbb Z_{16}\oplus \mathbb Z_{25})\\ \cong 
\large \mathbb Z_{2}\oplus \mathbb Z_{400}$

$\mathbb Z_{32}\oplus \mathbb Z_{25} \cong 
\large \mathbb Z_{800}$